# Sendkeys not working in Cucumber even tried with JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, cucumber-junit

Sendkeys are working in selenium cucumber. I have tried with Javasript executer but not working. Even my locators are correct. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my Sample code:

@Then("^user enters username and password$")

```
public void user_enters_username_and_password(){
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  // WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']"));
    /*WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
   email.click();
   email.clear();
   email.sendKeys("sanjeev.kumar@holisollogistics.com");*/
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('email').value='sanjeev.kumar@holisollogostics.com';");
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant html? Is it inside an iframe?

Comment: add the stack trace you are getting if you can? what version of chrome driver do you have?

Comment: its not inside a frame